# Container preventing children from being jquery ui draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a container ( #container ) that contains everything, but it is preventing dragging, through jquery UI, on its children. Clicking works, but not dragging. Any idea on how I can get its children ( .dataCard ) to still be draggable?

Here is a link to the page where this is happening: http://goo.gl/I7k18n

Edit: Here is some more information:

The ... means there is more ( often unnecessary ) code .

Here is the CSS of the `#container`:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
}
```

and here is the html that makes it up:

```
<div id="container">...</div>
```

and here is the code that makes the `.dataCard' draggable ( it works fine until the container contains the element it is applied to ):

```
$('.dataCard').not('.spelling, .focused, .greeting').draggable({
    axis:'x',
    ...
});
```

Comment: please post the relevant parts of the code here

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay, I did so